# CDK virtual scroll has no doms

Tags: html, angular, angular-material, angular-cdk, angular-cdk-virtual-scroll

I'm using CDK virtual scroll to improve the performance of a dropdown which will have huge data. I have followed all the steps as per the documentation. But when I open the dropdown I don't see any dom with in cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport component.

Here is the code from HTML.

```
<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport itemSize="500" class="example-viewport">
            <div *cdkVirtualFor="let item of items" class="example-item">{{item.name}}</div>
        </cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
```

If I move the div outside the cdk virtual scroll and replace it with ngFor it works fine. Any idea what could be the issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the scrolling module was not imported in the correct module file. It didn't give any error but was giving just a warning.

Answer (score 1):

That happens because your `itemSize` is too big for the container height.

virtual scroll uses `itemSize` to calculate the number of items that fit into your viewport.

You are setting 500px as the size for each item, which is the size of the full `cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport` container. Try setting a smaller `itemSize`.

Also, here's an example of virtual-scroll I made (it may help you): https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-virtual-scroll-biwn6